# How to list Amazon S3 buckets matching lifecycle expiry set to X days?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

```
aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle --bucket Bucket_Name| jq '.Rules[].Expiration.Days'
```

It does give me expiry value. However, the challenge is if there is multiple expiry setup on a bucket how do we compare and send the email if expiry is more than X days.

I need to scan all our buckets in our aws account against lifecycle expiry and send email if any bucket has expiry set to more than X days.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You would be best-off writing a program to query the rules, apply your business logic and trigger the notifications.

This could run on an EC2 instance or your own computer.

Alternatively, you could write it as an **AWS Lambda** function that is triggered by **Amazon CloudWatch Events** on a regular basis. It could send a message to an **Amazon SNS** topic and people who want to receive the notification can subscribe to the SNS topic (eg via email).

Comment: Thanks! Lambda would be an ideal solution. However, m not so comfortable with languages that lambda supports. If any existing code that we can reuse.

Comment: You're welcome to search the web but what you're asking for is quite specific. Lambda supports node, Java, Python, C# and Go. Give it a try and if you have a specific problem, you can always ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda would be an option, but without code it looks not possible to get notifications on that

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=235364